# How can we describe a broad sense of taste?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, grammaticality, expressions, word-usage

How can we describe a broad sense of taste?

Can we say that we have a versatile taste?

Or is it more correct to say that we have a diverse taste?

Taste here is with reference to food.

Comment: Do you mean to describe the taste of a person who likes a wide variety of food? _Diverse_ fits that well. I would not use "flexible". _Trying_ food that you might not like is being flexible ( maybe even _adventurous_) and your tastes might _adapt_ or _expand_ once you taste a new food, but your tastes don't really _flex_ — that implies that they might flex back to their original state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> From the Oxford Dictionary
>
> [**Palate**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/palate) - A person’s appreciation of taste and flavor,
> especially when sophisticated and discriminating
>
> **[Eclectic](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/eclectic)** - Deriving ideas, style, or *taste* from a broad and diverse range of sources
>
> **[Piquancy](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/piquancy#piquancy__2)** - A pleasantly sharp and appetizing flavor; The quality of being pleasantly stimulating or exciting

I would say you have a wide or varied **palate**. Perhaps even a eclectic **palate**.

And though not found in any dictionary we can combine the affix -geusia (meaning the sense of taste) with appropriate prefix such as bene- (good, well, gentle) and get something like benegeusia meaning "a good sense of taste"

Comment: Thanks Yeshe. Are there other ways we can express ourselves? Because using words such as palate and eclectic (to describe the palate) just seems to make simple descriptions complex.

Comment: I was about to post "eclectic" as an answer before I saw you'd already mentioned it in yours. Might I suggest that you define "eclectic" (an online dictionary is fine) as it's a very appropriate word in this context?

Comment: Can I say I have an eclectic taste? Or I have an eclectic sense of taste? Which is correct and why?

Answer (score 1):

This is often referred to as "catholic tastes", with catholic (small 'c') meaning "very diverse" rather than belonging to the Catholic (large 'c') church.

https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/catholic

Answer (score 0):

{Definition taken from Dictionary.com}
Connoisseurship
/ˌkɒn əˈsɜr, -ˈsʊər/

Connoissuer: a person who is especially competent to pass critical judgments in an art, particularly one of the fine arts, or in matters of taste.

And 'taste' here means taste of food/drinks etc.

Comment: while I understand where you are coming from I think the OP meant the actual sense of tasting rather than someone skilled at tasting.

Comment: Hi Everyone, thanks for your responses. Yes, as Yeshe stated, I'm referring the sense of tasting as defined in the question.

Comment: @ YeShe, I wonder what it's got to do with where I come from. However, you can exercise your right of freedom of speech and live with whatever imaginations you have in your mind.